# WordPress pages do not save, what does this error mean?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I am getting this error on my WP site and do not know what it means or how to go about fixing it. Can anybody tell me what this means and how to fix this?

```
[21-Jan-2016 11:21:18 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /home/sites/website.co.uk/public_html/kite-dev/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3624
```

Also there is NO line 3624 in my functions.php I have made to edits to this file at all

Answer (score 1):

Some of your plugins have widget, which extends WP_Widget class, and in its constructor uses `parent::WP_Widget()` instead of `parent::__construct()`;

Make shure that all of your plugins are updated to the latest version. If this does not fix the problem you'll need to edit the widget code.

You can remove all of your widgets and put them back one by one, to check exactly which of them is problem one. And then in plugins widget code must edit  `parent::WP_Widget(params)` to `parent::__construct(params)`;

But generally, this is only PHP Notice, so for now you can ignore it while its author fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way would be to make WP_DEBUG false for now, in wp-config file of your site.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

It worked for me to hide the error, hope works for you as well.

Comment: this doesn't do anything, the pages still do not save

Comment: This response it's not good. You response put debug method off, but erro or problem persist.